# Opera 10 supports html5 audio tag but Opera 11?

Tags: html, opera, html5-audio

I have been working on a HTML5 project and I recently noticed Opera 10.60 supports audio tag perfectly but not latest version of Opera (version 11.00 build 1156).

you may try with URL: http://moztw.org/demo/audioplayer/ with Opera 11.00. I can see the audio player without problem but it just doesn't play the music.

My HTML code is as simple as :-

```
<audio controls src="media/vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
```

Comment: my question is why Opera 11 doesn't support audio tag as Opera 10 does? is it a bug in Opera 11 ? how do we work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera 11 for Mac has a few bugs related to CSS and audio control buttons.

Under certain circumstances, the audio player will appear, but the controls will be inactive. I've seen it happen when the element is floated or has a `display:block` style.

Oddly enough, if you set a background color or image on the element (`background: transparent` won't do it), it should work.

Comment: Thanks - this has been bugging me for a while, and was the only thing keeping me from declaring support for Opera on my site, http://html5beats.com/.  Used a transparent png background.  Lame, but works.